# JavaScript not working in MVC Razor page (AJAX is probably causing this)

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I return the result from Controller to View as in the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(decimal? x, decimal? y)
{

...
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<road>>(roads);
 return View(result);
}


In the View I have, 

function CallFunction() {

alert("test");
}

@if (Model != null)
{
   <text>alert("test");</text>
  @Html.Raw("CallFunction();");
}

  $.ajax({
          url: "Home/Index",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html",
          data: { val1: x, val2: y},

          success: function (data) {
                      
           },

          error: function (data)
           {
                //alert(data);
           }

           })
```

In the code above, the alerts do not work. When I replace "if (Model != null)" with "if (true)", the Javascript alerts work. I debugged and I am sure that  "if (Model != null)" evaluates to true. The goal here is to check the model properties for specific values and then alert the user. It has to be the AJAX call back to the controller (communication is continuously going on between the controller and the view) causing this not to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: Figured it out. Checked the model value in success function by returning JSON object from the controller.